# multiple checkbox post form

Tags: php, mysqli

The below code will only work with one checkbox and ignores the rest. Is there any way that I can have it to delete selected checkboxes? I have tried using `implode` but it gives me

`Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

```
  <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="id"  class="check" value = "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
 <?php echo $row['to_user'];?>
  <input type="submit" name="delete">
 </form>


    <?php

 if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
 $id =  $_POST['id']; 
 $ids = implode( ',', $id );

 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
 $stmt = $mydb->prepare("update messages set deleted = 'yes' where from_user = ?  and id = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $ids);
 $stmt->execute();

echo "Message succesfully deleted";
exit();}

?>
```

Comment: What is then form code?

Comment: Where is the implode part? There is only one input

Comment: @EmilioGort I have included it now.

Comment: @barmar already answered your issue

Comment: Where is the loop that processes the query result? Are you really creating a separate form for each checkbox, instead of multiple checkboxes in one form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the checkbox an array-style name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]"  class="check" value = "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

This will cause `$_POST['id']` to be an array of all the checked values. Then delete them in a loop:

```
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("update messages set deleted = 'yes' where from_user = ? and id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $id);
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You can't use a comma-separated list of IDs with `=`. You can use it with `id in (...)`, but you can't do parameter substitution with this because the number of elements isn't known. So the loop is th best way to do it.

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" }`

Comment: I don't believe you. That looks more like `var_dump($_POST['id'])`.

Comment: oh yeah.. it is  `NULL`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I meant `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: But if `$_POST['id']` contains that array, it should be setting `deleted = yes` for ID 4. I assume you're setting `$user` correctly, that isn't anywhere in the question.

Comment: `array(2) { ["id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } ["delete"]=> string(12)`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with my code for the checkbox. Make sure you're setting `$user` properly.

Comment: thanks I had left out `bind_param` many thanks works perfect.